# execute command in Windows VM using pyvmomi

Tags: python, vmware, vsphere, pyvmomi

I'm using vSphere and I want to execute commands remotely using Pyvmomi. I found a sample which is `execute_program_in_vm.py` but unfortunately it's only working for debian/ubuntu.

Is there anyway to execute command working for guest Windows remotely?

Thank you

Comment: is vmware tools installed?